# How to bind a JavaFX Slider to a Label that shows values from a List?

Tags: java, javafx

I have built this `Slider` using `JavaFX` which is binded to a `Label`. At the moment I managed only to make the `Slider` work on discrete values (from 0 to 15) and to display those values on a `Label`. I would like to display another kind of values, one for every of those 16 discrete values. Maybe from a list or whatever.
How can I achieve this?

**My implementation**

```
private Slider sampleRateSlider = new Slider (0, 15, 0);
private Label sampleRateLabel = new Label("Sample Rate");
private Label sampleRateValueLabel = new 
Label(Double.toString(sampleRateSlider.getValue()));

acquisitionModeTab.setConstraints(sampleRateLabel,0, 1);
acquisitionModeTab.setConstraints(sampleRateSlider, 1, 1);
sampleRateSlider.setShowTickLabels(true);
sampleRateSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
sampleRateSlider.setMajorTickUnit(5);
sampleRateSlider.setMinorTickCount(5);
sampleRateSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
acquisitionModeTab.setConstraints(sampleRateValueLabel, 2, 1);
sampleRateValueLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
```

**Listener inside `initialize()` method in my controlles class:**

```
 sampleRateSlider.valueProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
        new_val = Math.round(new_val.doubleValue());
        sampleRateSlider.setValue(new_val.doubleValue());
        System.out.println(new_val.intValue());
        sampleRateValueLabel.setText(new_val.toString());
    });
```

Everything is working, but I would like to achieve what I asked above and I do not know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Label sampleRateValueLabel = new Label(getDisplayString(0));
```

```
sampleRateSlider.valueProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
    int value = (int) Math.round(new_val.doubleValue());
    sampleRateSlider.setValue(value);
    System.out.println(value);
    sampleRateValueLabel.setText(getDisplayString(value));
});
```

The `getDisplayString` method should use a suitable data structure to come up with the `String` to return. `List<String>` indeed is a good choice, but `String[]` or `Map<Integer, String>` would work as well:

```
private static final String[] STRINGS = new String[] {
         "s", "t", "a", "c", "k", "o", "v", "e",  "r", "f", "l", "o", "w", "c", "o", "m"
    };

private static String getDisplayString(int value) {
    return STRINGS[value];
}
```